# HTML5 Video stuttering/not running fluently / Buffer and preloading

Tags: firefox, cross-browser, html5-video, buffer, opera

I've a video playing on my homepage. My html looks like this:

```
<video id="player" style="display: inline;">
   <source id="src1" type="video/webm" src="uploads/tx_frmovieportfolio/film_05.webm">
   <source id="src2" type="video/ogg" src="uploads/tx_frmovieportfolio/film_05.ogv">
   <source id="src3" type="video/mp4" src="uploads/tx_frmovieportfolio/film_05.mp4">
   Your Browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

i am changeing sources via jQueryby clicking links. I am also constructed my own controlbar. Verything works ine with it. But:

In Chrome the videos are loaded very fast and they are played very well with no problems. 
in Firefox 24 and Opera 12.16 the video loading is slow and it is pausing all the time. I think it is loading new frames. it needs a lot of time for that. i tried it with autobuffer and preload="true" too, even the second one is outdated. but it doesnt change anything.

Is there any workaround, any thing I can do to make it fast working in all actual browsers? Otherwise it makes no sense to use video tags.

Would be great to get some ideas or maybe a perfect solution. :) .

Falk

Comment: Try preload="auto". Try also to change order of the webm and ogg source links. What dimension (wxh) does the video have?

Comment: I tried preload auto and true, also changed the order of the sources. The problem is still the same. The video has a dimension of 1280x720px. But it is played in a container with about 400x230px. The size of the player is set to max 100%. So the video seems smaller.Now I tried to let the video play in original size. But also this doesnt fix my problem. Sometimes it freezes for almost 1 minute.

Comment: If you drag and drop the video files directly from your file system into Opera/Firefox in an empty tab, does the video formats play fine? *If* they play fine, could you post the more of the HTML (and JS if any related to the video) that you have.

Comment: it's much better now. What I did:
1.) A mistake have been the preload attr. . I couldn't really see this, but the questionmarks have not been the right ones. They looked quite a bit different and the browser interprated this wrong. :/

2.) Again I changed the order of the sources. Now I have at the first place ogv for firefox, then mp4 for opera and then webm for ..i forgot. thats the best order with almost no freezings. Chrome doesnt has a problem at all. The other both yes. And I dont know how it is working in IE, I am not using this browser. I have to check later.

Thank you for your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Seven years after your question I ran into the same problem.  The issue at hand is that your browser is trying to buffer very large video files and some browsers handle it better than others.  On top of that you're at the mercy of the speed of their internet connection and available memory.

The solution is to transcode your video into [Apple's HTTP Live Streaming (HLS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming) format.  It's the [most widely supported format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming) as of 2020 and it works by splitting your video into short H.264/H.265 encoded clips, each with a duration of only a few seconds and stored as individual files. A manifest (.m3u8) is generated that acts as an index that your video player reads to only download the segments that you need.

Here's an example of how to transcode an MPEG2 video into HLS VOD format using FFMPEG:

```
ffmpeg -i InputVideo.mpg -vf scale=w=352:h=240:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -c:a aac -ar 44100 -b:a 64k -c:v h264 -profile:v main -crf 20 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -sc_threshold 0 -b:v 700k -maxrate 900k -bufsize 1400k -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type vod -hls_segment_filename hls/%03d.ts hls/OutputVideo.m3u8
```

Raw browser support for HLS is getting better with Chrome Android > v70, Android Browser and, Safari >= 6 all supporting HLS natively.  You can achieve near universal compatibility by instead using [JWPlayer](https://www.jwplayer.com) or [Video.js](https://videojs.com) instead of the HTML5 video object.

Comment: I agree that HLS is the way to go, but you do need a JavaScript based player,  the browser support listed in this response is incorrect.  Only Safari supports HLS natively. (reference [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=hls))

Comment: Thank you, I've updated the list of supported browsers.  Safari isn't the only browser to support HLS however as many of the most common mobile browsers support it including Chrome Android.  Sadly it looks like Chrome desktop will never support HLS according to a post in the  [https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=761506#c2](chromium bug tracker).